# How do you calculate discriminants of higher degree polynomials?

Tags: abstract-algebra, discriminant

I have a degree 6 polynomial with coefficients in terms of $a$ that I want to calculate the discriminant of. Is there an easy way to do this like an online calculator? The issue I am having is that searches I have done have only yielded online calculators that won't accept variable coefficients.

To be clear, the result I am looking for is the discriminant as a function of the coefficients of my degree 6 polynomial.

Comment: The _resultant_ of the polynomial and its derivative is a determinant, which, although producing large polynomials, may be implemented in more symbolic algebra software systems than "discriminant".

Comment: Here is something, but not degree $6$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant#Degree_4

Comment: Use Wolfram Alpha. I can't write the formula here https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Discriminant%5Ba+x%5E6+%2B+b+x%5E5+%2B+c+x%5E4+%2B+d+x%5E3+%2B+e+x%5E2+%2B+f+x+%2B+g%2C+x%5D

Comment: [Here's a SageMathCell](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxtyssKwjAQRuG94DvMMpEheO-m9RlsXJYKP9qGgWYCiUJ9e-ve7fmOdzW2jB1jzzgwjowT43yhhq5p-miKgsmLBtO2XNn16ubq-Y_6hcYll3c0nXdh0GJsJ_1mvguNKZOQKGVoGExl-9_tnlIeWaIo9GXsF_sdKfE=&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==) that computes it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer for degree 6 polynomials takes a long time to find. Wolfram Alpha (https://www.wolframalpha.com/) produces several terms before the computation time is exceeded. You can type in "discriminant a x^3 + b x^2 + c x + d" as the query for a cubic, for example. Do you have a more specific question about the discriminant in this case, or is it just something out of interest?

A general formula for the discriminant of a univariate polynomial of degree $n$ is $\Delta(f) = (-1)^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}} a_n^{2n - 2} \prod_{i < j} (x_i - x_j)^2$ where $a_n \not= 0 $ is the coefficient of $x^n$ in $f$ and $x_1, \ldots x_n$ are the roots of $f$.

This is the Product Formula, equation (1.23)  in "Discriminants, Resultants and Multidimensional Determinants" by I.M. Gelfand et al., Birkhaueser, 1994, Chapter 12, page 403.

In Mathematica v 12, it is given by the Discriminant[*poly, var*] function.  MAPLE has a similar function, discrim(p, x). For a quadratic, it finds $b^2 - 4ac$ for example.

For a univariate polynomial of degree 6, $a1 x^6 + a2 x^5 + \cdots + a7$, the discriminant begins:
$a2^2 a3^2 a4^2 a5^2 a6^2 - 4 a1 a3^3 a4^2 a5^2 a6^2 - 
 4 a2^3 a4^3 a5^2 a6^2 + 18 a1 a2 a3 a4^3 a5^2 a6^2 - 
 27 a1^2 a4^4 a5^2 a6^2 - 4 a2^2 a3^3 a5^3 a6^2 + 
 16 a1 a3^4 a5^3 a6^2 + 18 a2^3 a3 a4 a5^3 a6^2 - 
 80 a1 a2 a3^2 a4 a5^3 a6^2 - \cdots$

Comment: The product formula in the book seems to have a typo. It should read $\Delta(f) = (-1)^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}} a_n^{2n - 2} \prod_{i \not= j} (x_i - x_j)$

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. For context, I was trying to solve for the coefficients of my degree 6 polynomial that make the discriminant 0, as this is when my polynomial transitions from having all imaginary roots to having a real root (with multiplicity >1). This happens when $\Delta=0$, so I wanted to compute the discriminant in terms of the coefficients of my polynomial.

Comment: I'm happy it is answered the question.